# Android Launcher Shows Calculator activity layout but does nothing

Tags: java, android

Hi i'm working on a Android Launcher that Shows Calculator activity. It shows the  layout fine but does nothing when you click on any of the buttons I need help I have tried everything I can and i'm getting upset! any help would be amazing!!

Calculator.java:

```
package com.dva.schooltoolshome;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calculator extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView calculatorDisplay;
    private static final String DIGITS = "0123456789.";
    private Boolean userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("@###########");

    CalculatorBrain brain;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // hide the status bar and other OS-level chrome
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

        brain = new CalculatorBrain();

        calculatorDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        df.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
        df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(8);

        findViewById(R.id.button0).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button6).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button7).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button9).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonSubtract).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonToggleSign).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonDecimalPoint).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonEquals).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonClear).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonClearMemory).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonAddToMemory).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonSubtractFromMemory).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonRecallMemory).setOnClickListener(this);

        // The following buttons only exist in layout-land (Landscape mode) and require extra attention.
        // The messier option is to place the buttons in the regular layout too and set android:visibility="invisible". 
        if (findViewById(R.id.buttonSquareRoot) != null) {
            findViewById(R.id.buttonSquareRoot).setOnClickListener(this);
        }   
        if (findViewById(R.id.buttonInvert) != null) {
            findViewById(R.id.buttonInvert).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        if (findViewById(R.id.buttonCos) != null) {
            findViewById(R.id.buttonCos).setOnClickListener(this);
        }   
        if (findViewById(R.id.buttonSin) != null) {
            findViewById(R.id.buttonSin).setOnClickListener(this);
        }

//      Another way to hide the window title and actionbar, but only in newer sdk's
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
//            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
//            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
//            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//            actionBar.hide();
//        }
    }

    // @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String buttonPressed = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
        // String digits = "0123456789.";

        if (DIGITS.contains(buttonPressed)) {
            // digit was pressed
            if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {
                calculatorDisplay.append(buttonPressed);
            } else {
                calculatorDisplay.setText(buttonPressed);
                userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true;
            }
        } else {
            // operation was pressed
            if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {
                brain.setOperand(Double.parseDouble(calculatorDisplay.getText().toString()));
                userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;
            }

            brain.performOperation(buttonPressed);
            calculatorDisplay.setText(df.format(brain.getResult()));

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save variables on screen orientation change
        outState.putDouble("OPERAND", brain.getResult());
        outState.putDouble("MEMORY", brain.getMemory());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore variables on screen orientation change
        brain.setOperand(savedInstanceState.getDouble("OPERAND"));
        brain.setMemory(savedInstanceState.getDouble("MEMORY"));
        calculatorDisplay.setText(df.format(brain.getResult()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

CalculatorBrain.java:

```
package com.dva.schooltoolshome;

public class CalculatorBrain {
    // 3 + 6 = 9
    // 3 & 6 are called the operand.
    // The + is called the operator.
    // 9 is the result of the operation.
    private double operand = 0;
    private double waitingOperand = 0;
    private String waitingOperator = "";
    private double calculatorMemory = 0;

    public void setOperand(double operand) {
        this.operand = operand;
    }

    public double getResult() {
        return operand;
    }

    // used on screen orientation change
    public void setMemory(double calculatorMemory) {
        this.calculatorMemory = calculatorMemory;
    }

    // used on screen orientation change
    public double getMemory() {
        return calculatorMemory;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Double.toString(operand);
    }

    protected double performOperation(String operator) {

        /*
        * If you are using Java 7, then you can use switch in place of if statements
        *
        *     switch (operator) {
        *     case "MC":
        *         calculatorMemory = 0;
        *         break;
        *     case "M+":
        *         calculatorMemory = calculatorMemory + operand;
        *         break;
        *     }
        */

        if (operator.equals("MC")) {
            calculatorMemory = 0;
        } else if (operator.equals("M+")) {
            calculatorMemory = calculatorMemory + operand;
        } else if (operator.equals("M-")) {
            calculatorMemory = calculatorMemory - operand;
        } else if (operator.equals("MR")) {
            operand = calculatorMemory;
        } else if (operator.equals("C")) {
            operand = 0;
            waitingOperator = "";
            waitingOperand = 0;
            calculatorMemory = 0;
        } else if (operator.equals("Sqrt")) {
            operand = Math.sqrt(operand);
        } else if (operator.equals("1/x")) {
            if (operand != 0) {
                operand = 1 / operand;
            }
        } else if (operator.equals("+/-")) {
            operand = -operand;
        } else if (operator.equals("sin")) {
            operand = Math.sin(operand);
        } else if (operator.equals("cos")) {
            operand = Math.cos(operand);
        } else {
            performWaitingOperation();
            waitingOperator = operator;
            waitingOperand = operand;
        }

        return operand;
    }

    protected void performWaitingOperation() {

        if (waitingOperator.equals("+")) {
            operand = waitingOperand + operand;
        } else if (waitingOperator.equals("*")) {
            operand = waitingOperand * operand;
        } else if (waitingOperator.equals("-")) {
            operand = waitingOperand - operand;
        } else if (waitingOperator.equals("/")) {
            if (operand != 0) {
                operand = waitingOperand / operand;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

activity_calculator.xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAddToMemory"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="M+" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSubtractFromMemory"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="M-" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonRecallMemory"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="MR" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="C" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonToggleSign"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="+/-" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="/" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="*" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="@string/button7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="@string/button8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="@string/button9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="-" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="@string/button4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="@string/button5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="@string/button6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="+" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:baselineAligned="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".33"
                        android:text="@string/button1" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".33"
                        android:text="@string/button2" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".34"
                        android:text="@string/button3" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button0"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".66"
                        android:text="@string/button0" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonDecimalPoint"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".34"
                        android:text="." />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonEquals"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="=" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/apps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/wbrowser"
            android:background="@drawable/appdrawer"
            android:src="@drawable/appdrawer" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wbrowser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/browser" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wbrowser"
            android:background="@drawable/appdrawer"
            android:src="@drawable/appdrawer" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageButton01"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Tools" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonClearMemory"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ImageButton01"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tools"
            android:layout_marginBottom="163dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="MC" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm still new to android development so please don't judge

Regards

Rapsong11

Answer (score 0):

First of all use switch statement in OnClick(View v) function for every button.
like this.

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
case R.Id.button1
// the functionality code goes here

break;

case R.id.button2

break;
}
```